# How to set value in Select2 when using remote source in 4.0.3 js

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

There is a scenario in my application we have show tags saparated value in control so we choose select 2 .

```
  <select id="ddlGulfEmployee" multiple="multiple" style="display: none; 
 width: 
 100%;" class="form-control"></select>

 </script>`$("#ddlGulfEmployee").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '@System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Home/GetMasterUser")',// '@Url.Action("GetMasterUser","Home") %>', //"../GetMasterUser",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            debugger;
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var arr = []
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                //debugger;
                arr.push({
                    id: value.ID,
                    text: value.FirstName
                })
            })
            return {
                results: arr
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: function (people) {
        debugger;
        //debugger;
        if (people.loading)
            return people.text;

        var markup = '<option value="' + people.id + '">' + people.text + '</option>';

        return markup;
    },
    templateSelection: function (people) {
        debugger;
        return people.value || people.text
    }
    //,
    //initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    //    debugger;
    //    callback($.map(element.val().split(','), function (id) {
    //        return { id: id, text: id };
    //    }));
    //}
});
$("document").ready(function () {//I WANT LIKE THIS OPTION 
    //1 russell 
    $('#ddlGulfEmployee').select2('val', ["test1", "test2"], true);

});
```

`

When we are saving data and getting from remote source its working fine but the problem is when we want to show saved value back to control on page load during editing .

Please help me.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Suppose we saved '1 as id and ashish as text' during add. we want to get back it from database during editing the things

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

Here you need to pass data in format of key and values.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
        $("#ddlGulfEmployee").select2({
               data: [
                {
                  id: '1',
                  text: 'option 1'
                },
                {
                  id: '2',
                  text: 'option 2'
                },
                {
                  id: '3',
                  text: 'option 3'
                }

              ]
        });
    });
```

You can check in select2 as well [here](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data)

Hope this helps.

Comment: After that my autocomplete functionlity will not work as i think

Comment: After loading all the data in select2 you need to bind autocomplete related process once again.

Comment: Please suggest the syntex 
it gives following error:-
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Comment: You are right due to some reason autocomplete bind is not working.I mean code after adding data in array format ajax process is stop working.